# Writing Phone Numbers in US

Tags: text, typography

Is there any typographically correct or the most common way of writing *mobile* phone numbers in the US on websites/apps and in printed materials?

Examples:

```
+1 (555) 123 4567
+1 (555) 123-4567
+1 555 123 4567
+1 555 123-4567
1-555-123-4567
1.555.123.4567
555.123.4567
555-123-4567
```

Answer (score 2):

(555)123-4567 is the most common way phone numbers are conveyed WITHIN the U.S. However, if you wish to convey a more international presence then +1(555)123-4567 is better.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that no spaces are common in the US. Phone numbers for years and years have been written in this format:

(CCC)_PPP-NNNN

Where:

C = area code, 3 digits

_ = space

P = prefix digits, also called a local code. At one time these used letters and numbers to be pronounceable, as in "Clearwater 5" for "CL5" (corresponding to the digits 255).

N = Phone number digits.

I do not recommend unusual typography such as using periods as separators. The only simple and relatively common formatting is to just use numbers and the hyphen as a separator: ###-###-####

Comment: Thank you. What about parentheses? Are there any guides or logic when to use and to not use them?

Comment: Traditionally in the US, parentheses are used around the area code. But they are often omitted, the numbers are just written as shown at the end of my answer. I think they help with separating the numbers, but this is just a formatting (style) decision. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

1(555)123-4567   (no letter spacing and no + before the 1)

This is the typical way phone numbers are conveyed in the U.S. although, any of your examples above would get the message across.

There is no differentiation between a mobile number and a land line number. The most common way to convey that a number is mobile has been to just add the word *mobile* or *cell* in front of the number

mobile +1(555)123-4567

Comment: It depends on the use case, generally the spacing helps keep a cleaner look ex: `(555) 123-4567`
You probably only need to show the +1 at the beginning if you're displaying the numbers to users/audience with international numbers.